# My lowpoly character went smooth, how to unsmooth it

Tags: objects

My lowpoly character went smooth and i don't know what i did wrong. I can't go back with ctrl + Z and i don't know how to retreive my lowpoly look. If i edit my object i still got my hard edges so there should be a way to unsmooth it. I don't have any Modifier except a Mirror

[image: both characters]

[image]

Comment: in Object mode, right click > Shade Flat?

Comment: thanks @moonboots !! it's okay now :) i'm new to blender so i didn't know this option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must have right clicked > *Shade Smooth*, it has smoothed the shading between the faces. So in *Object* mode, right click again > *Shade Flat*